# Does -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled work with the -XX:+UseSerialGC option in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection

It's all in the question. The more information on the matter, the better. I'm having issues in an application where it seems like my class space is never being GC'd, hence running me out of memory on a 512m Heroku dyno.

Answer (score 0):

`CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` refers to CMS, the ConcurrentMarkSweep collector, which is not the serial collector which you select via `UseSerialGC`. There is a more general setting `ClassUnloading`, which defaults to true and thus does not need to be set explicitly.